# Difference between CONVERT TO and just resetting the CHARSET?

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

Just wondering what is the difference in the below when running them on an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8, COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

...and

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHARSET=utf8, COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Like when changing the table charset wouldn't it be converted anyway?